# VBA Excel Script Save as TXT CSV, UFT-8, set specific field and txt delimeter and Quote all TXT cells

Tags: excel, vba

I have been trying for a few days to crack this.

We have a Lotus Notes DB that will only accept and import of a file only if it is saved in this method

1) Opening a XLS in Open Office

2) Selecting all cells (always a single worksheet) and setting Default Formatting

3) Saving as TXT CSV

4) Then as part of the exporting process Saving as UTF-8, Field Delimiter = , text Delimiter = " AND Quote all TXT Cells

I have looked around at various pieces, and I cannot seem to be able to find exactly what I need. Would love some assistance

Here is what I have so far

```
Sub OTimport()
    ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Cells.ClearFormats

    Set wkb = ActiveSheet
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim MaxCols As Integer
    fileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("C:\Users\ADMIN\Desktop\Report work\OTIMPORT" & Format(Now(), "DD-MMM-YYYY hh mm AMPM"), "CSV File (*.csv), *.csv")

    If fileName = "False" Then
        End
    End If

    On Error GoTo eh
    Const adTypeText = 2
    Const adSaveCreateOverWrite = 2

    Dim BinaryStream
    Set BinaryStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    BinaryStream.Charset = "UTF-8"
    BinaryStream.Type = adTypeText
    BinaryStream.Open

    For r = 1 To 10
        s = ""
        C = 1
        While Not IsEmpty(wkb.Cells(r, C).Value)
            s = s & wkb.Cells(r, C).Value & ","
            C = C + 1
        Wend
        BinaryStream.WriteText s, 1
    Next r

    BinaryStream.SaveToFile fileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
    BinaryStream.Close

    MsgBox "CSV generated successfully"

    eh:

End Sub
```

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: If I read the description correctly then you need to add the double quotes for each string value? I don't see that you are adding them anywhere. Have you tried this s = s & chr(34) & wkb.Cells(r, C).Value & chr(34) & "," ? chr(34) is for adding double quotes.